# Ericsson f3507g WWAN (3G Broadband) and AT commands

Tags: c#, windows-vista, wireless, modem, terminal-emulator

I have a lenovo x200t tablet with WWAN built into it.

I'm trying to connect to the internet using AT commands and a C# program which I am making so that the program can connect to the net and upload information on demand.

I don't want to use Lenovo's "Access Connections" as it is too complicated for the end user.

So far I have been able to use terminal to turn the card on and off, ring landlines and send SMS messages. However I can't seem to access the internet using it.

I could access the net through it before I removed "Access Connections" software/bloatware.

The commands I am using to try and access the net are:

1. Connect on COM7 to the modem
2. Send initialisation string "AT+CFUN=1"
3. Send AT*ENAP=1,1 as suggested here (http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Ericsson_F3507g_Mobile_Broadband_Module)

Windows says it is "Identifying" the network and a yellow exclamation mark appears on the networking icon in the task bar, but the connection fails and drops off.

An IP is assigned to the "Local Area Connection 2" of 169.254.1.192 with a subnet of 255.255.0.0 - no gateway or DNS.

Definately no net connection...

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in contact with Vodafone in Australia and

1. their towers were not compatible with my modem. This has subsequently been fixed.
2. I needed a public IP from them (at no cost)

Problem solved..